# Matplotlib: Show selected date labels on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

In my matplotlib graph, the datetime x axis is currently formatted with

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dt.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dt.DateFormatter('%d %b'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dt.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
```

[image: Current graph]

I want to have labels for minor ticks, but only some values. Expected:

[image]

What `minor_formatter` should I use?

Answer (score 2):

The minor ticks need to have selective labels - showing only on days with specific values. To select dates, I came up with my own Formatter which takes a predicate (function returning true/false when passed a datetime) which wraps a DateFormatter to actually format the string. This allows a more general approach (you can for instance show only weekends)

```
import matplotlib.dates as dt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

class SelectiveDateFormatter(ticker.Formatter):

    def __init__(self, predicate, date_formatter, tz=None):
        if tz is None:
            tz = dt._get_rc_timezone()
        self.predicate = predicate
        self.dateFormatter = date_formatter
        self.tz = tz

    def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
        if x == 0:
            raise ValueError('DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is '
                         'an illegal date; this usually occurs because '
                         'you have not informed the axis that it is '
                         'plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()')
        current_date = dt.num2date(x, self.tz)
        should_print = self.predicate(current_date)
        if should_print:
            return self.dateFormatter(x, pos)
        else:
            return ""

    def set_tzinfo(self, tz):
        self.tz = tz
```

You can use it like this to reach my example:

```
predicate = lambda d: d.day % 10 == 0
format = dt.DateFormatter('%d')
selective_fmt = SelectiveDateFormatter(predicate, format)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(selective_fmt)
```

Or for showing only weekends:

```
predicate = lambda d: d.weekday() >= 5
...
```